# What's the name of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I searched around a bit and could not found any sorting algorithm that described this way to sort. I do understand that it has no real use as it's terribly inefficient. Here it is in Ruby:

```
def swap(array, i)
  array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
end

def compare(array, i)
  array[i] > array[i+1]
end

def sort(array)
  i = 0
  until i + 1 == array.length
    if compare(array, i)
      swap(array, i)
      i = 0
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end
  return array
end
```

Comment: `... ? true : false` sucks. It gives me a very bad impression.

Comment: `swap` always makes me think of bubble sort, but I'm not promising.

Comment: that's a really slow insertion sort.  If you did `i-=1` after swap instead of `i=0`, it would be more obvious.

Comment: If instead of `i = 0` you had an outer loop that stops if you didn't make any swaps it would be bubble sort. Right now it's a slow variation of bubble sort (with equal number of swaps, but more traversing).

Comment: Is there something like a sorting algorithm signature? E.g. calling `sort([5,4,3,2,1])` and `sort([1,2,3,4,5])`, looking at all the steps needed and comparing them against other algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

This is [Gnome sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort) kind - walking from the beginning until order violation occurs, then swapping, but here position resets to array begin.